# angularJs unique Filter - not getting unique array length

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/

I am using the above Angularjs-filter library to use unique property in ng-repeat.

below  is my code

```
<div class="rankblock" ng-repeat="item in sports.Ranks.Rank  |unique:'_position'>
<span> {{sports.Ranks.Rank.length}}</span> //
</div>
```

after unique in ng-repeat my Rank array length becomes 6 but it still shows 9 (the original Arr length) in the output.

Comment: The filter only affect the data being displayed, not the original array so `sports.Ranks.Rank.length` is displaying the original length as expected. [See this article](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/08/tip-accessing-filtered-array-outside-ng-repeat/) to get what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter internally returns into `ng-repeat` a *new array*. This is the idea of the filter - to filter but avoid changing the input. In other words:

```
ng-repeat="item in sports.Ranks.Rank  | unique:'_position'
```

says ng-repeat to go through the result of the filter function, which is a new array without duplicates, when here

```
<span> {{sports.Ranks.Rank.length}}</span>
```

you still read the length of the original one.

If you want to display the new array length you can do e.g. try the following

```
{{ (sports.Ranks.Rank | unique:'_position').length }}
```

(did never do things like that, maybe this works), still this is not a performant solution. In fact what I would do is deduplication on a controller level.

Comment: yes it return the original array length..not the unique array length

Answer (score 1):

As you can refer to https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/blob/master/src/_filter/collection/unique.js This filter returning a new array of objects. Hence its not changing your original object.